Excel - Create Dropdown to choose 1 item from each of 3 different lists in a single cell
I'm working on a spreadsheet and need to find a way so that when you click on a dropdown in a cell in a particular column, it asks you to choose 1 item from each of 3 different lists, and displays them in that cell.
So, for example, each row of the sheet shown in 'Main sheet' below would have someone's details in it, and when you click into column D you will have to choose 1 item from each of the 3 lists in the List picture. The cell would then populate with the 3 chosen terms.
List

Main sheet

Can this be done please?
Not sure where to start with this. I could easily create 3 separate columns, one for each list, and complete it that way, but I'm told we need to have all this combined into a single column as there will be a lot more columns being used.

So you have 3 lists and use 1 cell to choose 1 option of each of 3 columns combined. Best option if you ask me is to approach it differently. Have 3 separate dropdowns and combine these choices afterwards (if you need these combined).
